# Windows DNS not responding to chaos class

Tags: windows, dns

I have a Windows DNS server, I cannot get it to respond to chaos class requests. Is there something that I can do to allow this to work?

The DNS server is running in AWS.

I'm running the following command to check:

```
nslookup -class=chaos -type=txt hostname.bind 192.168.1.2
```

I have also tried to another record in the DNS server. These all timeout. If I do a standard IN class request it works fine.

The issue has come about for some external parties talking to our DNS server. This used to work 'apparently' but now it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

'apparently' Windows DNS post 2008R2 has EnableVersionQuery switched off by default. Did you recently upgrade, or harden your DNS Servers?

Switch it back on by modding your registry:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DNS\Parameters]
"EnableVersionQuery"=dword:00000001
```

You can try this instead of regedit: `dnscmd <servername> /config /EnableVersionQuery 1` I prefer the direct edit method for this change.

Then use `nslookup -q=txt -class=CHAOS version.bind <servername>` to test

You may need to restart the DNS service to have it take.

James DS